# How to use raster calculator to sum multiple bands' value of a raster layer in QGIS Graphical Modeler?

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, qgis-modeler, netcdf

I have 12 bands in a raster layer which I would like to sum up to produce a single layer. Interestingly, the raster calculator tool does the job while running it (QGIS interface)[ but fails to do so while running it in the graphical modeler.
I tried using the "Cell Statistics" and "r.series" tools which failed to produce the desired result.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you manage to solve your issue? Thank you!